# Why are the Visual Studio 2010 icons blurry when compared to the Visual Studio 2005 icons?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

[image: http://imgur.com/5Grp6]

That image shows what I'm talking about.
Visual Studio 2010 on the left, Visual Studio 2005 on the right.

If you ignore the jpeg compression artifacts you can tell that the left icons are much blurrier than the right icons.

Is there some way to turn off this anti-aliasing?

Comment: I believe this is similar to why Office 2010 icons are blurry -- there is a transition to "device independent" rendering. The older rendering was very pixel-oriented. Not so the new WPF and similar. But it may just be the way the images were designed. My eyes aren't that good anymore (and that could explain it all :-). The different font sizes may "land" or "not land" on a clean real-device pixel (and be clear or blurry) or they may trigger different rendering modes.

Answer (score 1):

Developers seem to have a strong urge to change every icon people are used to, to be fancy, 3D and anti-aliased.

What was wrong with Office icons only god knows. Or why the clear and yellow speaker icon got replaced by two concentric circles, with 3d effects.

Comment: Ahh I think it had something to do with the font and font size.
I was using Courier New size pt. 12 when the icons were blurry but I've since switched to Proggy Clean size 12 and they are no longer anti-aliased.  
Also if I crank the font size up to ProggyClean 14 they go blurry again so I think the problem was just me misusing the fonts.
PS. Proggy is a pretty damn good font.